# How to suppress emails from being sent from vpn-xxxxxxxxx with VPN single-tunnel notification/VPN redundancy loss events

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge, aws-vpn

**How to supress below emails as they are being recieved very frequently ..**

My client mentioned they were using cisco equipment.. which would not support dual tunnels, but supports only active/passive tunnels, Hence we would like to stop these alerts being generated ..(see description)

i have reviewed and found same alert in AWS Health Dashboard ,but could not found any option to suppress this type of alert Any one can help on this issue,  I can open ticket with AWS team , but want to know if these changes can be modified ?? Does suppress alarms would cause any issues ?

**Description**

You're receiving this message because you have at least one VPN Connection in the us-east-1 Region, for which your VPN Customer Gateway is not using both tunnels. This mode of operation is not recommended as you may experience connectivity issues if your active tunnel fails.

The VPN Connection(s) which do not currently have both tunnels established are associated with this event.

You can obtain the VPN Connection configuration recommendations for several types of VPN devices from the AWS Management Console [1]. On the "Amazon VPC" tab, select "VPN Connections". Then highlight the VPN Connection and choose "Download Configuration".

**OR**

**Your VPN Connection associated with this event in the us-west-2 Region had a momentary lapse of redundancy as one of two tunnel endpoints was replaced. Connectivity on the second tunnel was not affected during this time. Both tunnels are now operating normally.

Reviewed : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/s2svpn/monitoring-vpn-health-events.html#single-tunnel-notifications

need technical guidance to resolve this issue.